# Insert space when needed with Regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have to write a function that looks up for a string and check if is followed/preceded by a blank space, and if not add it here is my try :

```
public string AddSpaceIfNeeded(string originalValue, string targetValue)
    {
        if (originalValue.Contains(targetValue))
        {
            if (!originalValue.StartsWith(targetValue))
            {
                int targetValueIndex = originalValue.IndexOf(targetValue);
                if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(originalValue[targetValueIndex - 1]))
                    originalValue.Insert(targetValueIndex - 1, " ");
            }
            if (!originalValue.EndsWith(targetValue))
            {
                int targetValueIndex = originalValue.IndexOf(targetValue);
                if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(originalValue[targetValueIndex + targetValue.Length + 1]) && !originalValue[targetValueIndex + targetValue.Length + 1].Equals("(s)"))
                    originalValue.Insert(targetValueIndex + targetValue.Length + 1, " ");
            }
        }
        return originalValue;
    }
```

I want to try with Regex :
I tried like this for adding spaces after the targetValue :

```
Regex spaceRegex = new Regex("(" + targetValue + ")(?!,)(?!!)(?!(s))(?= )");
originalValue = spaceRegex.Replace(originalValue, (Match m) => m.ToString() + " ");
```

But not working, and I don't really know for adding space before the word.

Example adding space after:
AddSpaceIfNeeded(Hello my nameis ElBarto, name)
=> Output Hello my name is ElBarto

Example adding space before:
AddSpaceIfNeeded(Hello myname is ElBarto, name)
=> Output Hello my name is ElBarto

Comment: Give us some sample input/output

Comment: Try `Regex.Replace(originalValue, $@"(?<=\S)({targetValue})(?=\S)|(?<=\S)({targetValue})(?!\S)|(?<!\S){targetValue}(?=\S)", m => m.Groups[1].Success ? $" {targetValue} " : m.Groups[2].Success ? $" {targetValue}" : $"{targetValue} ")`

Comment: See https://ideone.com/e8hXlh

Comment: I added an input/output example

Comment: This actualy what i need, really elegant !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match your word in all three context while capturing them in separate groups and test for a match later in the match evaluator:

```
public static string AddSpaceIfNeeded(string originalValue, string targetValue) 
{
  return Regex.Replace(originalValue, 
        $@"(?<=\S)({targetValue})(?=\S)|(?<=\S)({targetValue})(?!\S)|(?<!\S){targetValue}(?=\S)", m => 
          m.Groups[1].Success ? $" {targetValue} " : 
           m.Groups[2].Success ? $" {targetValue}" : 
            $"{targetValue} ");
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/e8hXlh)

Note you may need to use `Regex.Escape(targetValue)` to escape any sepcial chars in the string used as a dynamic pattern.

**Pattern details**

- `(?<=\S)({targetValue})(?=\S)` - a `targetValue` that is preceded with a non-whitespace (`(?<=\S)`) and followed with a non-whitespace (`(?=\S)`)
- `|` - or
- `(?<=\S)({targetValue})(?!\S)` - a `targetValue` that is preceded with a non-whitespace (`(?<=\S)`) and not followed with a non-whitespace (`(?!\S)`)
- `|` - or
- `(?<!\S){targetValue}(?=\S)` - a `targetValue` that is not preceded with a non-whitespace (`(?<!\S)`) and followed with a non-whitespace (`(?!\S)`)

When `m.Groups[1].Success` is `true`, the whole value should be enclosed with spaces. When `m.Groups[2].Success` is `true`, we need to add a space before the value. Else, we add a space after the value.

Comment: Thanks, I need to ignore adding spaces sometimes for comma for example, I tried adding (?!,) but not working

Comment: @ELBartoTn You need to subtract comma from the `\S` - replace all `(?<=\S)` with `(?<=[^,\s])` and all `(?=\S)` with `(?=[^\s,])`. See [the regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5b%5e%2c%5cs%5d%29%28name%29%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%2c%5cs%5d%29%7c%28%3f%3c%3d%5b%5e%2c%5cs%5d%29%28name%29%28%3f!%5cS%29%7c%28%3f%3c!%5cS%29name%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%2c%5cs%5d%29&i=Hello+my%2cname+is+ElBarto&r=).

Comment: @mickmackusa Sorry, I have not heard of encoding attacks. [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) just warn of *An invalid subject will cause the preg_* function to match nothing*, but I have not seen such "subjects".